# Missing header 'Authorization' of type [java.lang.String]

Tags: java, spring

I have a client app that communicates to the spring server with REST type calls using basic authentication.
The controller method signature is below:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/REST/clients", method = RequestMethod.POST)
protected ModelAndView postClients(@ModelAttribute("ClientsCommand") ClientsCommand cmd,
        @RequestHeader("Authorization") String credentials) throws IOException {
...
}
```

The problem I have is that if no Authorization is present in the header I get an error:

```
Missing header 'Authorization' of type [java.lang.String]]
```

Whereas, I was kind of hoping the credentials string would just be empty. How do I stop the error from occurring and just receive a blank string if no authorization header entry was sent?

Comment: And now ask us to find a question for your problem? :-D

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try toggling `required=false` on the `@RequestHeader`.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/REST/clients", method = RequestMethod.POST)
protected ModelAndView postClients(@ModelAttribute("ClientsCommand") ClientsCommand cmd,
        @RequestHeader(value = "Authorization", required=false) String credentials) throws IOException {
...
}
```

When the `@RequestHeader` is configured as required, Spring won't map a request to your handler when the header isn't there.  By making it optional, your handler will be invoked as you're hoping (i.e. regardless of the header's presence).